# Is there any way to get windows task manager details through tsql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, windows-10

I do not have access to the client's windows remote machine,I connect their database server through tsql only.I need to check what processes taking more memory and inform them.
Is there any tsql query to get windows processes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can call [TASKLIST](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491010.aspx) command via [xp_cmdshell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx):

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'TASKLIST'
```

Output:

```
Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
System Idle Process              0                            0          4 K
System                           4                            0        140 K
smss.exe                       212                            0        956 K
csrss.exe                      332                            0      5,560 K
.....
sqlservr.exe                  1492                            0     92,012 K
sqlservr.exe                  1532                            0     95,928 K
.....
```

Note: you should have the correct permissions and Server configuration options to run xp_cmdshell. Read the remarks section in MSDN to understand how to enable xp_cmdshell

Comment: Everything is fine cha.But it did not show any sql server process is running

Comment: SQL Server process is called `sqlservr.exe`

Comment: If this is not enabled, you can turn it on with this:  sp_configure xp_cmdshell,1
reconfigure

Comment: Is there any chance to order the output based on memory used?Because the output in the cmdshell format.