# get list of running processes in t-sql

Tags: sql-server, windows, t-sql

is it possible to get list of running processes (applications in windows) in T-SQL?

**.exe name or ProcessID.**

this list precisely
[image]

Comment: Yes it is possible. And it only takes a hint of effort to search for it. Here is the results from google for the title of your question. https://www.google.com/search?q=get+list+of+running+processes+in+t-sql&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1

Comment: @SeanLange you are wrong!! read the question carefully. the link you provided is by no mean close to what i have asked.

Comment: why you need to know it in sql server? window has its own task manager

Comment: What are you trying to determine? The processes running on the SQL Server machine? The processes *connected* to SQL Server? It's rather unclear at the moment. Maybe also say what you'd *do* with that list of processes since what you're trying to do may not even be possible.

Comment: it`s some kind of complicated business logic, i need to check if a program is not running then do some stuff in a trigger.

Comment: LOL. Did you even try? Had you looked at the links returned google you would found multiple references to sys.dm_exec_sessions. This would show you all the current sessions open. As for the exe...well...that isn't really possible unless you have a process name defined in the connection.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever processess running on the machine!! "(Applications in windows)".

Comment: @SeanLange wtf, sys.dm_exec_sessions dose not return the PID or exe name. have you tried? if you don`t know the answer stop trolling then.

Comment: I would hope that your application server and database server are not the same machine. And I am not trolling you. It is not clear what you are trying to do. Have you looked at sp_who? That will give you the spid.

Comment: I voted to close as too broad.

Comment: @SeanLange i tried 'exec sys.sp_who2' and also 'exec sys.sp_who2' but no luck, it dose not return the complete list.

Comment: @JacobH how can it be so broad? (select * from running_processess?)

Comment: SQL Server isn't an operating system.

Comment: @JacobH are you joking man? please leave if you do`nt know the answer. do not spam.

Comment: @SHM relax. What you are asking for is very strange. You are trying to find running processes on the operating system where sql server is running. Most people have their applications on a completely different machine which adds to the confusion. You have not done a great job explaining what you are trying to do which is why so many people are confused here.

Comment: @SeanLange added a picture to make it more clear.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42640548/is-there-any-way-to-get-windows-task-manager-details-through-tsql

Comment: @JacobH great! that did the trick. thanks dude.

Comment: @JacobH you might post that as answer for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do this in TSQL.  You could write a CLR procedure that uses .NET to do this.  But TSQL can't be used to access the operating system.